# Pyspark reduceByKey with (key, Dictionary) tuple

Tags: python, dictionary, mapreduce, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm stuck a bit in trying to do a map-reduce on databricks with spark. I want to process log files and I want to reduce to a (key, dict()) tuple.

However I'm always getting an error. I'm not hundert percent sure if that's the right way to do it. I'd be very glad about any advice. As a result I want to have a everything mapped to a (key, dict(values).

This are my Mapper and Reducer

```
from collections import defaultdict


a = {u'1058493694': {'age': {u'25': 1}, 'areacode': {'unknown': 1}, 'catg': {'unknown': 1}, 'city': {'unknown': 1}, 'country': {'unknown': 1}, 'ethnicity': {'unknown': 1}, 'gender': {u'u': 1}, 'geo_data': {'unknown': 1}, 'user_ip': {u'149.6.187.*': 1}}}
b = {u'1058493694': {'age': {u'25': 1}, 'areacode': {'unknown': 1}, 'catg': {'unknown': 1}, 'city': {'London': 1}, 'country': {'unknown': 1}, 'ethnicity': {'unknown': 1}, 'gender': {u'Male': 1}, 'geo_data': {'unknown': 1}, 'user_ip': {u'149.6.187.*': 1}}}

def getValueFromJson(json_obj, field):
  try:
    raw = dict(json_obj)
    if field in raw:
        if raw[field]:
          return {raw[field]: 1}
  except:
    return {'unknown': 1}
  return {'unknown': 1}

def mapper(line):
  attr = dict(defaultdict())
  user_id = line.get("user_id", "unknown")
  user_attr = ["age", "gender"]
  location_attr = ["city", "state", "post_code", "country", "areacode", "user_ip", "geo_data"]

  # combine both lists
  attr_list = user_attr + location_attr

  for item in attr_list:
    attr[item] = getValueFromJson(line, item)

  return (user_id, attr)

def reducer(a, b):
  results = dict()
  for key in a.keys():
    val = dict()
    for k in a[key].keys() + b[key].keys():
      val[k] = a[key].get(k, 0) + b[key].get(k, 0)
    results[key] = val
  return results
```

I'm not sure If I can use the reducer the way I'm doing it. Any help on best practices to achieve my goal would be appreciated.

```
user_pairs = imps_data.map(extractUserData)
user_totals = user_pairs.reduceByKey(joinUserData)
user_totals.take(25)
```

I'm then getting following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-461-e1b93b972cac> in <module>()
      1 user_pairs = imps_data.map(extractUserData)
      2 user_totals = user_pairs.reduceByKey(joinUserData)
----> 3 user_totals.take(25)

/home/ubuntu/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in take(self, num)
   1263 
   1264             p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry, totalParts))
-> 1265             res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p, True)
   1266 
   1267             items += res

/home/ubuntu/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/context.pyc in runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
    895         mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
    896         port = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions,
--> 897                                           allowLocal)
    898         return list(_load_from_socket(port, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))
    899 

/home/ubuntu/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    536         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    537         return_value = get_return_value(answer, self.gateway_client,
--> 538                 self.target_id, self.name)
    539 
    540         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/home/ubuntu/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    298                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    299                     'An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n'.
--> 300                     format(target_id, '.', name), value)
    301             else:
    302                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 6 in stage 688.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 6.3 in stage 688.0 (TID 8308, 10.179.246.224): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/home/ubuntu/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2318, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/home/ubuntu/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2318, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/home/ubuntu/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 304, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "/home/ubuntu/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1746, in combineLocally
    merger.mergeValues(iterator)
  File "/home/ubuntu/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 266, in mergeValues
    for k, v in iterator:
  File "<ipython-input-456-90f3cdb37d50>", line 5, in extractUserData
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 733 (char 732)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:315)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1266)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1411)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Thank you very much
C

Comment: An exception is thrown, by the JSON decoder in the part of the code you didn't provide here (`extractUserData`). Probably some kind of malformed entry.

Comment: Thanks! Posted my solution below

Answer (score 2):

thanks for the advice. That's what it was.

I simply added a filter on the rdd filtering out lines that have invalid json

```
data = sc.textFile(files, 20).filter(lambda line: isJson(line.split("||")[0]))

import json

def isJson(myjson):
  try:
    json_object = json.loads(myjson)
  except ValueError, e:
    return False
  return True
```